# Dynamically changing words in websites

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, text

I was wondering how to cycle through a series of words so that they change every, say, 5 seconds or so. Is there anyway to do this? (I expect it would involve JavaScript)

The effect can be seen here: http://www.tivix.com/

Answer (score 2):

> This is quite simple and does **not** require jQuery
>
> __ **Here is a example** __

```
var words = ['hello world', 'foo bar', 'john smith', 'my name'], // 1
    element = document.body, // 2
    currentWord = -1; //3

window.setInterval(function(){ // 4
   currentWord++; // 5
   if(currentWord > words.length) currentWord = 0; // 6
   element.textContent = words[currentWord]; // 7
}, 5000); // -- 4
```

---

> ## [JSFiddle Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/CrDkj/1)

---

> ## Steps
>
> 1. It's just a Array of words
> 2. The element the words will be going into
> 3. The index of the current word. Set to -1 because we will be adding 1 before changing the text
> 4. Create a function that loops every 5000ms ( 5 seconds )
> 5. Increment the currentWord ( + 1)
> 6. If the currentWord ( index ) is a higher number than the length of the words array 
>      Then set it back to default ( 0 )
> 7. Set the elements text to the current word

---

> ## Now if you want it to be random then it's slightly different
>
> __ **Here is a example** __

```
var words = ['hello world', 'foo bar', 'john smith', 'my name'], // 1
    element = document.body, // 2
    currentWord = 0; // 3

var getRandom = function() { // 4
    return parseInt(Math.random()*words.length); // 5
}; //  -- 4


window.setInterval(function(){ // 6
    var newWord = getRandom(); // 7
    while(newWord === currentWord) newWord = getRandom(); // 8
    currentWord = newWord; // 9
   element.textContent = words[currentWord]; // 10
}, 5000); // -- 6
```

---

> ## [JSFiddle Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/CrDkj/3)

---

> ## Steps
>
> 1. It's just a Array of words
> 2. The element the words will be going into
> 3. The index of the current word.
> 4. Create a function that returns a random number
> 5. Get a random number & times is by the length of the word Array - parse it.
> 6. Create a function that loops every 500ms ( 5 Seconds )
> 7. Create a variable that holds the new word index
> 8. If the newWord number is the same as the currentWord then try another random number
> 9. Set the currentWord the the value of newWord
> 10. Set the elements text to the new word

Comment: Hi @iConnor, thanks for this great snip, but how can I specify the word who change ? With a css selector for exemple ? Many thanks

Comment: Hello @iConnor, your script works great but after the last word it goes blank. Anyway to fix that? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

5Yea, it's pretty easy in jQuery

You can create an array of the words you want interchanged like so:

```
var words = new Array('word1','word2','word3');
```

Then you can set an interval to constantly loop through the array.

```
var i = 0;
setInterval( function(){
    $( '#wordDiv' ).empty().append( words[ i ] );
    if( i < words.length ) {
        i++;
    } else {
        i = 0;
    }
}, 5000 );
```

So what the interval does is it will loop forever (unless you choose to break it), with a break of 5 seconds (5000 milliseconds) between each iteration. The i counter is used to point to the next array position: `i++` (if there is one - if not it will move back to the start of the array `i = 0`).

If you want this in javascript without jquery just say.